# MongoDB / EJS: How to make synchronous query and render result values in EJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, callback

**I'm struggling a little bit with the concepts of asynchronous programming and I would appreciate some help/guidance from someone.** 
Basically, I'm developing a node.js web server that's connected to a mongodb database.
I'm using EJS to generate HTML files as you can see below.

```
app.get("/", function(req, res){
    res.render('home', {date: getData.todaysDate(), n: getData.todaysIncidents(), nTot: getData.totalIncidents()});
});
```

Most of these values ('n' and 'nTot') are obtained by querying my database and then doing some other operations, as you can see in the following example code sample.

```
//------getData.js------//
exports.todaysIncidents = function() {
let server_n = 0;
Incident.find({dia: {$gt:y}}, function(err, result) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else{
        //do some stuff...
        server_n = 12345
        }
    }
});
return server_n;
```

};

**Here is the problem:** The values printed in the HTML file are always those used for variable initialization, such as 0 for variable 'server_n'. After doing some research, I understand that this happens because .find(...) is an asynchronous function so the program executes right away the instruction "return server_n;", which means that on the HTML file the value showed will be 0 and not 12345.

I already looked at other questions here in StackOverflow, but I'm struggling to understand a possible fix to this issue, I mean I can't be the only one going through this, right?

Could you please provide some basic explanation of how I could go around this issue? I'm still learning and a lot of these concepts remain hard to understand.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are right that the problem is as a result of improper handling of asynchronous operations like querying the DB. So how do you fix it?

**Using async/await:**
There are multiple options to handle asynchronous operations in NodeJS, however, I would strongly recommend using async/await, it's syntactically clean and easy to understand.
To put it simply, async/await is a way of specifying and dealing with asynchronous operations. You use the `async` keyword to specify that a function is asynchronous, and you use the `await` keyword to wait for an asynchronous operation. One key thing to note is that you can only use the `await` keyword inside an `async` function. You can read more about async/await [here](https://javascript.info/async-await).
If your nodeJS version is 7.6 or higher, async/await is supported out of the box, however, if you are using a lower version and can't upgrade, you can set up build tools like [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) to be able to use javascript features supported in newer ECMAScript spec.

When using async/await, your code should be something like this.:

```
//------getData.js------//
// NOTE: the typeof todaysIncidents is not more the regular function, 
// it's now an AsyncFunction because of the async keyword
exports.todaysIncidents = async function () {
  let server_n = 0;
  try {
    // In simple terms, the await keyword here would ensure that the DB query
    // resolves or reject before moving on to the next statement
    const incident = await Incident.find({ dia: { $gt: y } });
    // The incident variable stores the result of the query
    server_n = 12345
  } catch (err) {
    // Handle error from the DB query
    console.log(err);
  }
  return server_n;
};
```

.

```
//------The router------//
// NOTE: You also need to make the route handler an AsyncFunction
app.get("/", async function (req, res) {
  // You can await the differeint DB queries in here to ensure they resolve(or reject) before rendering the view
  const todaysDate = await getData.todaysDate();
  const todaysIncidents = await getData.todaysIncidents();
  const totalIncidents = await getData.totalIncidents();
  res.render('home', { date: todaysDate, n: todaysIncidents, nTot: totalIncidents });
});
```

Comment: Hello, thank very much for the response. It's starting to make some sense now. I did more research, tried your code and I magically got it to work, I guess!
 I have another question regarding the use of async and await in for loops. Suppose I have a classic for(let i =0; i < array.length; i++) loop, and I want to query my database for every 'i' and update each element array[i]. Does this work the same way? I tried to adapt your code and it didn't work. I also looked at google and apparently this is not that easy to accomplish.
Thank you very much once again

Comment: Using await in a for/loop should work fine as long as the for/loop is enclosed in an async function. However, when working with async/await in javascript loops, there are some gotchas you need to be aware of, you can check out this [article](https://zellwk.com/blog/async-await-in-loops/), it explains it in details.